# Storybook addDecorator does not work from config.js?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

For the sake of experiment I put the following decorator into my Button.stories.tsx

```
const stories = storiesOf('Button', module)
stories.addDecorator(story => <div style={{backgroundColor: 'red', width: '500px', height: '100px'}}>{story()}</div>)
stories.add('with text', () => <Button>Hello Button</Button>)
```

It displayed button on top of red rectangle as expected.
But when I put the same decorator inside .storybook/config.js like this

```
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react'
addDecorator(story => <div style={{backgroundColor: 'red', width: '500px', height: '100px'}}>{story()}</div>)
```

it does not have any effect! Could the problem be caused by @storybook/react version? When I was trying to make storybook work with typescript I had to upgrade this package from 3.4.8 version to 4.0.0-alpha.10. Here are some versions from my package.json:

```
"react": "^16.4.1",
"react-dom": "^16.4.1",
"react-scripts-ts": "2.16.0",
"@storybook/react": "4.0.0-alpha.10",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use the `makeDecorator` function from `@storybook/addons`:

See:
https://storybook.js.org/addons/writing-addons/#the-addon

Remember also to register the addon in `.storybook/addons.js` as in:
https://storybook.js.org/addons/writing-addons/#register-the-addon